# ModelSim Issue - Discrepancy of Data Output Results from ModelSim versus Altera's VWF Editor

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, intel-fpga

I am instantiating two components within a top level file, where this implements a Phase Accumulator and LUT with an 8-bit FTW, to essentially create a simple DDS system. Mind you this is very simplified and is for testing purposes only.

The issue lies with two separate results where the Quartus VWF editor is correctly outputting the locations from the LUT (this is auto-configured with a ROM component from the MegaWizard tool) of which they are stored in this `.mif` file. I had read somewhere that the relative path may trigger ModelSim to throw an error or warning about this but have not encountered this.

The waveform signals from the built-in **VWF on Quartus** gives the following, which is correct:

[image: Quartus]

**ModelSim signals:**:

[image: ModelSim]

There is no output on `data_out`, so why are the results different?

The phase accumulator output is working correctly however, therefore does this issue lie with the testbench or architecture of the top-level file?

#### Top-Level:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;
library altera_mf;
library lpm; 
use lpm.lpm_components.all;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

entity DDS_top is
    PORT ( 
            clk         : in std_logic;
            fsw_in      : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
            pa_probe_out : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
            data_out    : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
        );
              
end DDS_top;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

architecture DDS_top_bhv of DDS_top is

    component PA_comp
        PORT
        (
            CLK     : IN STD_LOGIC  := '1';
            FSW     : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);
            DATA_OUT    : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0)
        );
    end component;
    
    component LUT_comp
        PORT
        (
            CLK     : IN STD_LOGIC  := '1';
            DATA_IN : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);
            DATA_OUT    : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0)
        );
    end component;
    
    signal pa_data_out : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');

begin

    phase_acc   :   PA_comp
            PORT MAP (
                CLK     =>  clk,
                FSW     =>  fsw_in,
                DATA_OUT    =>  pa_data_out
            );
            
    pa_probe_out <= pa_data_out;
            
    lut_rom :   LUT_comp
            PORT MAP (
                CLK     =>  clk,
                DATA_IN =>  pa_data_out,
                DATA_OUT    =>  data_out
            );

end DDS_top_bhv;
```

#### Testbench:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;

entity DDS_tb is
end DDS_tb;

architecture DDS_tb_bhv of DDS_tb is

   signal clk : std_logic := '0';
    signal fsw_in : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
     
   signal pa_probe_out : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal data_out : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');

   constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;

begin

    uut: entity work.DDS_top
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            fsw_in => fsw_in,
            pa_probe_out => pa_probe_out,
            data_out => data_out
        );

   -- Clock process def.
    clk_process : process
    begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
    end process;

   stimulus_process: process
   begin
        fsw_in <= "00000001";
        wait for 1000 ns;
            
        fsw_in <= "00000010";
        wait for 1000 ns;
            
        assert false report "Simulation complete" severity note;

   end process;

end DDS_tb_bhv;
```

Note that I have tried to move around the `.mif` file as I believe this isn't the issue. The issue may lie in the LUT component but as seen above it works as intended according to the Quartus VWF editor.

#### `LUT_comp.vhd`:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;
library altera_mf;
library lpm;
use lpm.lpm_components.ALL;

entity LUT_comp is
   PORT (
      clk      : in std_logic;
        data_in  : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
      data_out : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
   );
end LUT_comp;

architecture LUT_comp_bhv of LUT_comp is
    -- ROM PHFQ
    component rom_phfq
        PORT
        (
            address     : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);
            clock       : IN STD_LOGIC  := '1';
            q       : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0)
        );
    end component;

begin  
   -- MEM0 for full cycle 
    mem_init : rom_phfq
        PORT MAP
        (
            address     => data_in,
            clock   => clk,
            q           => data_out
        );

end LUT_comp_bhv;
```

#### `phfq_comp.vhd`:

```vhdl
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

LIBRARY altera_mf;
USE altera_mf.all;

ENTITY rom_phfq IS
    PORT
    (
        address     : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);
        clock       : IN STD_LOGIC  := '1';
        q       : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END rom_phfq;


ARCHITECTURE SYN OF rom_phfq IS

    SIGNAL sub_wire0    : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);



    COMPONENT altsyncram
    GENERIC (
        clock_enable_input_a        : STRING;
        clock_enable_output_a       : STRING;
        init_file       : STRING;
        intended_device_family      : STRING;
        lpm_hint        : STRING;
        lpm_type        : STRING;
        numwords_a      : NATURAL;
        operation_mode      : STRING;
        outdata_aclr_a      : STRING;
        outdata_reg_a       : STRING;
        widthad_a       : NATURAL;
        width_a     : NATURAL;
        width_byteena_a     : NATURAL
    );
    PORT (
            address_a   : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);
            clock0  : IN STD_LOGIC ;
            q_a : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0)
    );
    END COMPONENT;

BEGIN
    q    <= sub_wire0(7 DOWNTO 0);

    altsyncram_component : altsyncram
    GENERIC MAP (
        clock_enable_input_a => "BYPASS",
        clock_enable_output_a => "BYPASS",
        init_file => "mem_init.mif",
        intended_device_family => "Cyclone II",
        lpm_hint => "ENABLE_RUNTIME_MOD=NO",
        lpm_type => "altsyncram",
        numwords_a => 256,
        operation_mode => "ROM",
        outdata_aclr_a => "NONE",
        outdata_reg_a => "CLOCK0",
        widthad_a => 8,
        width_a => 8,
        width_byteena_a => 1
    )
    PORT MAP (
        address_a => address,
        clock0 => clock,
        q_a => sub_wire0
    );



END SYN;
```

#### `PA_comp.vhd`:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;
library altera_mf;
library lpm;
use lpm.lpm_components.ALL;

entity PA_comp is
    Port (
        clk      : in std_logic;
        fsw       : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); -- Assuming an 8-bit FTW
        data_out : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end PA_comp;

architecture PA_comp_bhv of PA_comp is
        
     signal add_out : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');  
     signal q_out : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');

begin
     -- LPM_ADD_SUB for phase accumulator
     addnsub : lpm_add_sub
          generic map (
                LPM_WIDTH       => 8,
                LPM_DIRECTION  => "ADD"
          )
          port map (
            DATAA      => fsw,  
            DATAB      => q_out,        
            RESULT     => add_out   
        );
          
    -- LPM_FF for phase accumulator
    dff : lpm_ff
        generic map (
            LPM_WIDTH  => 8,
            LPM_FFTYPE => "DFF"
        )
        port map (
            DATA  => add_out,
            CLOCK => clk,
            Q     => q_out
        );
          
     data_out <= q_out;

end PA_comp_bhv;
```

ModelSim transcript output:

```
** Warning: (vsim-3473) Component instance "mem_init : rom_phfq" is not bound.
   Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /dds_tb/uut/lut_rom File: C:/altera/13.0sp1/projects/MWT-DDS-PROJECT/LUT_comp.vhd
** Warning: (vsim-8684) No drivers exist on out port /dds_tb/uut/lut_rom/data_out, and its initial value is not used.
Therefore, simulation behavior may occur that is not in compliance with
the VHDL standard as the initial values come from the base signal /dds_tb/data_out.
** Warning: (vsim-8684) No drivers exist on out port /dds_tb/uut/data_out, and its initial value is not used.
Therefore, simulation behavior may occur that is not in compliance with
the VHDL standard as the initial values come from the base signal /dds_tb/data_out.
```

#### `mem_init.mif` file:

```
DEPTH = 256;
WIDTH = 8;
ADDRESS_RADIX = HEX;
DATA_RADIX = BIN;

CONTENT

BEGIN
00 : 00000000;
01 : 00000011;
02 : 00000110;
03 : 00001001;
04 : 00001100;
05 : 00010000;
06 : 00010011;
07 : 00010110;
08 : 00011001;
09 : 00011100;
0A : 00011111;
0B : 00100010;
0C : 00100101;
0D : 00101000;
0E : 00101011;
0F : 00101110;
10 : 00110001;
11 : 00110011;
12 : 00110110;
13 : 00111001;
14 : 00111100;
15 : 00111111;
16 : 01000001;
17 : 01000100;
18 : 01000111;
19 : 01001001;
1A : 01001100;
1B : 01001110;
1C : 01010001;
1D : 01010011;
1E : 01010101;
1F : 01011000;
20 : 01011010;
21 : 01011100;
22 : 01011110;
23 : 01100000;
24 : 01100010;
25 : 01100100;
26 : 01100110;
27 : 01101000;
28 : 01101010;
29 : 01101011;
2A : 01101101;
2B : 01101111;
2C : 01110000;
2D : 01110001;
2E : 01110011;
2F : 01110100;
30 : 01110101;
31 : 01110110;
32 : 01111000;
33 : 01111001;
34 : 01111010;
35 : 01111010;
36 : 01111011;
37 : 01111100;
38 : 01111101;
39 : 01111101;
3A : 01111110;
3B : 01111110;
3C : 01111110;
3D : 01111111;
3E : 01111111;
3F : 01111111;
40 : 01111111;
41 : 01111111;
42 : 01111111;
43 : 01111111;
44 : 01111110;
45 : 01111110;
46 : 01111110;
47 : 01111101;
48 : 01111101;
49 : 01111100;
4A : 01111011;
4B : 01111010;
4C : 01111010;
4D : 01111001;
4E : 01111000;
4F : 01110110;
50 : 01110101;
51 : 01110100;
52 : 01110011;
53 : 01110001;
54 : 01110000;
55 : 01101111;
56 : 01101101;
57 : 01101011;
58 : 01101010;
59 : 01101000;
5A : 01100110;
5B : 01100100;
5C : 01100010;
5D : 01100000;
5E : 01011110;
5F : 01011100;
60 : 01011010;
61 : 01011000;
62 : 01010101;
63 : 01010011;
64 : 01010001;
65 : 01001110;
66 : 01001100;
67 : 01001001;
68 : 01000111;
69 : 01000100;
6A : 01000001;
6B : 00111111;
6C : 00111100;
6D : 00111001;
6E : 00110110;
6F : 00110011;
70 : 00110001;
71 : 00101110;
72 : 00101011;
73 : 00101000;
74 : 00100101;
75 : 00100010;
76 : 00011111;
77 : 00011100;
78 : 00011001;
79 : 00010110;
7A : 00010011;
7B : 00010000;
7C : 00001100;
7D : 00001001;
7E : 00000110;
7F : 00000011;
80 : 00000000;
81 : 11111101;
82 : 11111010;
83 : 11110111;
84 : 11110100;
85 : 11110000;
86 : 11101101;
87 : 11101010;
88 : 11100111;
89 : 11100100;
8A : 11100001;
8B : 11011110;
8C : 11011011;
8D : 11011000;
8E : 11010101;
8F : 11010010;
90 : 11001111;
91 : 11001101;
92 : 11001010;
93 : 11000111;
94 : 11000100;
95 : 11000001;
96 : 10111111;
97 : 10111100;
98 : 10111001;
99 : 10110111;
9A : 10110100;
9B : 10110010;
9C : 10101111;
9D : 10101101;
9E : 10101011;
9F : 10101000;
A0 : 10100110;
A1 : 10100100;
A2 : 10100010;
A3 : 10100000;
A4 : 10011110;
A5 : 10011100;
A6 : 10011010;
A7 : 10011000;
A8 : 10010110;
A9 : 10010101;
AA : 10010011;
AB : 10010001;
AC : 10010000;
AD : 10001111;
AE : 10001101;
AF : 10001100;
B0 : 10001011;
B1 : 10001010;
B2 : 10001000;
B3 : 10000111;
B4 : 10000110;
B5 : 10000110;
B6 : 10000101;
B7 : 10000100;
B8 : 10000011;
B9 : 10000011;
BA : 10000010;
BB : 10000010;
BC : 10000010;
BD : 10000001;
BE : 10000001;
BF : 10000001;
C0 : 10000001;
C1 : 10000001;
C2 : 10000001;
C3 : 10000001;
C4 : 10000010;
C5 : 10000010;
C6 : 10000010;
C7 : 10000011;
C8 : 10000011;
C9 : 10000100;
CA : 10000101;
CB : 10000110;
CC : 10000110;
CD : 10000111;
CE : 10001000;
CF : 10001010;
D0 : 10001011;
D1 : 10001100;
D2 : 10001101;
D3 : 10001111;
D4 : 10010000;
D5 : 10010001;
D6 : 10010011;
D7 : 10010101;
D8 : 10010110;
D9 : 10011000;
DA : 10011010;
DB : 10011100;
DC : 10011110;
DD : 10100000;
DE : 10100010;
DF : 10100100;
E0 : 10100110;
E1 : 10101000;
E2 : 10101011;
E3 : 10101101;
E4 : 10101111;
E5 : 10110010;
E6 : 10110100;
E7 : 10110111;
E8 : 10111001;
E9 : 10111100;
EA : 10111111;
EB : 11000001;
EC : 11000100;
ED : 11000111;
EE : 11001010;
EF : 11001101;
F0 : 11001111;
F1 : 11010010;
F2 : 11010101;
F3 : 11011000;
F4 : 11011011;
F5 : 11011110;
F6 : 11100001;
F7 : 11100100;
F8 : 11100111;
F9 : 11101010;
FA : 11101101;
FB : 11110000;
FC : 11110100;
FD : 11110111;
FE : 11111010;
FF : 11111101;
END;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please post a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You do not provide the code for all components, meaning we have no way of knowing where the problem might be. It appears the modelsim version has no output. How do you know the .mif is actually loaded?

Comment: @Tricky edits made to post. Not sure what you mean by _It appears the modelsim version has no output_

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. A minimal, complete, and verifiable example would include the entities and architectures for PA_comp and LUT_comp.  You don't appear to be using any declarations from packages numeric_std, std_logic_unsigned or lpm_components in either DDS_top or DDS_tb. Their use clauses and library clauses for altera_mf and lpm are likewise superfluous. The testbench data_out has a default value of all zeros. Is lut_rom bound? (It's not illegal in VHDL to have unbound components).

Comment: @user16145658 I have added a MCVE in the edit.

Comment: Actually you still don't have a [mcve], note the lack of PA_COMP. Restoring end of line indications to the transcript for readability, the first warning demonstrates rom_phfq is not bound, remaining two point out the consequences. The Quartus II 9.1 Build 222 10/21/2009 altera_mf.vhd file analyzed into library altera_mf along with altera_mf_components for modelsim, contains an altsyncram model that will parse a .mif init file.

Comment: Without PA_comp there isn't a working design hierarchy, but I did get the dds_tb to elaborate with the Quartus II 9.1 altera_mf library analyzed from altera_mf_components.vhdl and altera_mf.vhd in order using ghdl. The mif init file ("mem_init.mif") also needs to be provided for a [mcve]. Without it the altsyncram caused an error opening the file causing simulation to end.

Comment: By creating an empty mem_init.mif file simulation would show pa_probe_out as all 'U's which is from the lack of the PA_Comp entity and architecture and any underlying design hierarchy.  The altera_mf source files can be found on [github](https://github.com/awersatos/AD/tree/master/Library/HDL%20Simulation/Altera%20QuartusII%209.1%20VHDL%20Libraries/lpm/src).  Without the actual mif file I couldn't verify the altsyncram model would load the mem_init.mif.

Comment: @user16145658 Apologies, I have added the .mif file and the PA_comp.vhd.

Comment: Note the clock period in Modelsim is 2.5 times longer than in VWF. Also you could `use altera_mf.altera_mf_components.all;` instead of altera_mf.all; and rely on the alsyncram component declaration there instead of a local component declaration in the architecture of rom_phfq. Your [mcve] simulates successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved by adding the `phfq_comp.vhd` to the project library in ModelSim, as this component was automatically created by the MegaWizard tool so I did not even think of adding this to the project library. Therefore, is it best practise to add all `.vhd` components to a ModelSim project? I assumed it would have had scope of instantiated components. [image: ModelSim DATA_OUT working as intended]